# sofware upgrades fails to update in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, package-management

I have a huge list of software upgrade after installing 11.10 via a alternate CD.
when i initiated the process, I get so many packages in failed state and only few get downloaded successfully

Comment: try a sudo apt-get update and please edit your post and add some error messages / other information

Answer (score 1):

Try to update only 20 -30 packages, if this succeeds, update another 20-30. That helps me when I have such a problem. I used to have it on Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

in detail try this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

that should be it. If any error occur copy and paste the terminal output here.

Comment: i get these errors like 
...  fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb Hash Sum mismatch
i then need to restart the upgrade process over and over again until all downloads happen successfully. If it downloads on restart, why does it fail with hash problem initially?

Comment: are behind a proxy server? Try changing the repository server to a different one. Go to software update manager - settings - ubuntu software - download from - change it to a server to something else. than run the update.

Comment: This time I choose the "server from U.S", and seems to work through. Thanks